# Multi application in 1 installed codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I want to create multi application (like admin app and user app) in 1 installed codeigniter 4. is it possible?

If it is possible, how about the session? it will have separated session between application or fall on each other. Thank you

Current my app structure :

[image]

Comment: Can you explain with more detail on what you mean by "Multi Project"? What are you trying to gain by going this way?

Comment: As @TimBrownlaw said this requires re-stating as a specific question. CodeIgnitor is a framework so you can do lots of things in different ways. Right now this question is probably more suited to another StackExchange site.

Comment: Sorry, i have edited my post, it should be application, like admin app and user app

Comment: 1 user 1 session 1 app: if you log in as admin, you have access to that area, if you log in as user you have access to user reserved areas, if you don't login you have access to the public part of your site

Comment: @Vickel, thank you. but may i know what is best folder structure to create multiple app in 1 spark?